# Double summation identity

Tags: summation

I'm trying to understand the following identity from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#General_manipulations)

$$\sum_{k\le j \le i\le n} a_{i,j} = \sum_{i=k}^n\sum_{j=k}^i a_{i,j} = \sum_{j=k}^n\sum_{i=j}^n a_{i,j} =
\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\sum_{i=k}^{n-j} a_{i+j,i}$$

There seems to be more than just index shifts involved. Can somebody explain the steps to me? Also how does one translate the index inequality in the first sum to a proper double sum? Are there some tricks one could use when being presented with some double sum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to understand it is to draw the set of couples $(i,j)$ such that

$$k\le j\le i\le n$$
as this

[image]

The cases where there are the stars are the set of desired couples and for example the first equality is to sweep these couples by rows:
$$\underbrace{(a_{k,k})}_{\text{first row}}+(a_{k+1,k}+a_{k+1,k+1})+\cdots+\underbrace{(a_{n,k}+a_{n,k+1}+\cdots+a_{n,n})}_{\text{last rows}}$$

Comment: Thank you, this is a great depiction and explanation!
I can finally understand, that the first equality is to sweep the couples by rows, the second by columns and the thirs just an index shift of the second.

Answer (score 2):

You already received an answer to the main question.

You can write the summation as:$$\sum_{i=k}^n\sum_{j=k}^n a_{i,j}[j\leq i]$$ where $[j\leq i]$ denotes the function that takes value $1$ if $j\leq i$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.

This to get rid of the inequality in the first sum.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality in $\sum_{k\le j \le i\le n} a_{i,j}$ means that you are summing up all $a_{i,j}$ with $i,j$ satisfying $k\le j\le i \le n$. ( $i, j$ are just **dummy variables** in this case)

It will make sense if you read the double summation from the left to the right. The first $\sum_{i=k}^n$ means that you are summing from $i=k$ to $i=n$ so it's necessary that $k\le i\le n$. Then you read the second sum, $\sum_{j=k}^i$, which means summing from $j=k$ to $j=i$, so it's necessary that $k\le j\le i$. Combining $k\le i\le n$ and $k\le j\le i$ yield $k\le j\le i \le n$.

For $\sum_{j=k}^n\sum_{i=j}^n a_{i,j}$, reading from the left to the right leads to $k\le j\le n$ and $j\le i\le n$, which again yield $k\le j\le i \le n$.

Finally, $\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\sum_{i=k}^{n-j} a_{i+j,i}$ indicates that $0\le j\le n-k$ and $ k\le i\le n-j$, which leads to $k\le i\le j+i \le n$. Then you notice in this case the terms are $a_{i+j,i}$ instead of $a_{i,j}$, but with the inequality changed it still means the same summation.

BTW, check out user296113's picture, it's easier to understand visually.

Answer (score 0):

The two indices $i$ and $j$ run from $k$ to $n$, with $j\leq i$.

In the second sum, you start with the index $i$ (from $k$ to $n$),
and then $j$ runs from $k$ to $i$ (as $j\leq i$).

In the third sum, you start with $j$ (from $k$ to $n$), and then
$i$ runs from $j$ to $n$.

In the last sum, there is a re-indexation. The indices $i$ and $j$
don't have the same meaning as before. If you want to understand better,
give them another name, say $p$ and $q$, so the last sum becomes
${\displaystyle \sum_{q=0}^{n-k}\sum_{p=k}^{n-q}a_{p+q,p}}$. Now,
in the second sum, put $j=p$ and $i=n-q$, that is $p=j$ and $q=n-i$.

So, when $i$ runs from $k$ to $n$, $q=n-i$ runs (backwards) from
$n-k$ to $0$. And $p=j$ runs from $k$ to $i=n-q$.